Why does my window in Java (JFrame) crash when i double click on a JTextField?
I wrote this little program for an specific utility, didn't optimize it yet but so far everything works as intended, but when I accidentaly double click on JTextField it crashes, and I have no idea why. (JTextField is on line 62 for the matter)
package smoothies;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class smoothies extends JFrame {
    
    public smoothies(List<List<List<String>>> smoothies) {
        //setBackground(new Color());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setSize(400,400);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(50,50));
        
        JPanel lIng= new JPanel();
        lIng.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,2));
        ArrayList<JCheckBox> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        // kelp,horse,grapes,apple,pepper,nectar,milk,cactus,potato,salt,butter,pumpkin,guts,fang,mango,egg
        JCheckBox kelp = new JCheckBox("kelp");
        ingredients.add(kelp);
        JCheckBox horse = new JCheckBox("horse");
        ingredients.add(horse);
        JCheckBox grapes = new JCheckBox("grapes");
        ingredients.add(grapes);
        JCheckBox apple = new JCheckBox("apple");
        ingredients.add(apple);
        JCheckBox pepper = new JCheckBox("pepper");
        ingredients.add(pepper);
        JCheckBox nectar = new JCheckBox("nectar");
        ingredients.add(nectar);
        JCheckBox milk = new JCheckBox("milk");
        ingredients.add(milk);
        JCheckBox cactus = new JCheckBox("cactus");
        ingredients.add(cactus);
        JCheckBox potato = new JCheckBox("potato");
        ingredients.add(potato);
        JCheckBox salt = new JCheckBox("salt");
        ingredients.add(salt);
        JCheckBox butter = new JCheckBox("butter");
        ingredients.add(butter);
        JCheckBox pumpkin = new JCheckBox("pumpkin");
        ingredients.add(pumpkin);
        JCheckBox guts = new JCheckBox("guts");
        ingredients.add(guts);
        JCheckBox fang = new JCheckBox("fang");
        ingredients.add(fang);
        JCheckBox mango = new JCheckBox("mango");
        ingredients.add(mango);
        JCheckBox egg = new JCheckBox("egg");
        ingredients.add(egg);
        for(JCheckBox ing: ingredients) {
            lIng.add(ing);
        }
        
        Button calculate = new Button("calculate");
        JTextField result = new JTextField("hai :D");
        result.setEditable(false);
        
        calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSMOOTHIES YOU CAN MAKE:");
                for(List<List<String>> smoothie: smoothies) {
                    for(JCheckBox ing1: ingredients) {
                        if(smoothie.get(0).contains(ing1.getText()) && ing1.isSelected()) {
                            for(JCheckBox ing2: ingredients) {
                                if(smoothie.get(1).contains(ing2.getText()) && ing2.isSelected()) {
                                    System.out.println(smoothie);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        Thread h = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    int p = 0;
                    for(List<List<String>> smoothie: smoothies) {
                        for(JCheckBox ing1: ingredients) {
                            if(smoothie.get(0).contains(ing1.getText()) && ing1.isSelected()) {
                                for(JCheckBox ing2: ingredients) {
                                    if(smoothie.get(1).contains(ing2.getText()) && ing2.isSelected()) {
                                        p++;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(p));
                }
            }
        });
        h.start();
        

        
        
        add(lIng,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(result,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(calculate,BorderLayout.EAST);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        List<List<List<String>>> smoothies = List.of(List.of(List.of("nectar"), List.of("nectar")),
                List.of(List.of("nectar"), List.of("milk")),
                List.of(List.of("grapes"), List.of("grapes")),
                List.of(List.of("grapes"), List.of("horse","apple","cactus","salt","butter","mango")),
                List.of(List.of("grapes"), List.of("nectar")),
                List.of(List.of("grapes"), List.of("milk")),
                List.of(List.of("milk"), List.of("milk")),
                List.of(List.of("milk"), List.of("apple","cactus")),
                List.of(List.of("milk"), List.of("salt")),
                List.of(List.of("mango"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("mango"), List.of("kelp","apple","cactus","butter")),
                List.of(List.of("nectar"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("milk"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("salt"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("cactus"), List.of("cactus","horse","nectar","pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("cactus"), List.of("salt")),
                List.of(List.of("pepper"), List.of("pepper")),
                List.of(List.of("pepper"), List.of("cactus","pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("pepper"), List.of("potato")),
                List.of(List.of("pepper"), List.of("grapes","apple","milk","mango")),
                List.of(List.of("apple"), List.of("apple")),
                List.of(List.of("apple"), List.of("horse","nectar","cactus","potato")),
                List.of(List.of("apple"), List.of("salt")),
                List.of(List.of("kelp"), List.of("kelp")),
                List.of(List.of("kelp"), List.of("grapes","apple","potato")),
                List.of(List.of("kelp"), List.of("pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("kelp"), List.of("milk")),
                List.of(List.of("kelp"), List.of("salt")),
                List.of(List.of("horse"), List.of("horse","kelp","pepper","nectar","potato","salt","mango")),
                List.of(List.of("horse"), List.of("milk")),
                List.of(List.of("potato"), List.of("potato")),
                List.of(List.of("potato"), List.of("grapes","cactus","butter")),
                List.of(List.of("nectar"), List.of("potato")),
                List.of(List.of("milk"), List.of("potato")),
                List.of(List.of("potato"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("potato"), List.of("salt")),
                List.of(List.of("butter"), List.of("butter","kelp")),
                List.of(List.of("apple"), List.of("butter")),
                List.of(List.of("cactus"), List.of("butter")),
                List.of(List.of("nectar"), List.of("butter")),
                List.of(List.of("butter"), List.of("pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("milk"), List.of("butter")),
                List.of(List.of("salt"), List.of("butter")),
                List.of(List.of("pumpkin"), List.of("pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("pumpkin"), List.of("horse","grapes","apple","potato")),
                List.of(List.of("nectar"), List.of("pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("milk"), List.of("pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("pumpkin"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("salt"), List.of("pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("egg","grapes","nectar","milk","salt")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("cactus")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("pepper")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("apple")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("kelp")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("horse")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("potato")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("butter")),
                List.of(List.of("egg"), List.of("pumpkin")),
                List.of(List.of("guts"), List.of("mango")),
                List.of(List.of("guts"), List.of("cactus")),
                List.of(List.of("fang"), List.of("pepper")),
                List.of(List.of("guts"), List.of("pepper")),
                List.of(List.of("guts"), List.of("apple")),
                List.of(List.of("fang"), List.of("kelp")),
                List.of(List.of("fang"), List.of("horse")),
                List.of(List.of("fang"), List.of("potato")),
                List.of(List.of("fang"), List.of("butter")),
                List.of(List.of("fang"), List.of("pumpkin")));
        
        
        System.out.println(smoothies);
        new smoothies(smoothies);
    }

}

You are not supposed to interact with it, and i did setEditable to false, but sometimes it just crashes out of nowhere, and other times it actualy sends the error
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad position: 1

that along something about caret, I don't understand what means this here
https://youtu.be/MxIIx3QBYw8


Class names should start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java conventions. All Java books and tutorial follow conventions. 2) Don't use a while (true) loop and a Thread. The infinite loop is causing some kinde of problem and will make the GUI unresponsive. Instead add an ActionListener to all the check boxes. In the ActionListener you can then  do your logic to track the number of items selected. 3) You are not supposed to interact with it, and i did setEditable to false, - you would typically use a JLabel for this.


A side note: make a String array of ingredients, such as, private static final String[] INGREDIENTS = { "kelp", "horse", "grapes", "apple", "pepper", "nectar", "milk", "cactus", "potato", "salt", "butter", "pumpkin", "guts", "fang", "mango", "egg" }; and then use this and for loops to help greatly simplify your code.

For future reference, it may help if the stack trace is included in the question body. You may also need to highlight the top line of your code that is referenced in the stack trace.

You should organize your code into reusable methods (and classes).
Use a singleton thread executor to spawn a loop to calculate the possible smoothies based on the currently selected ingredients.
Here is a refined updater method:
private void startSmoothieUpdater(List<Smoothie> smoothies) {
    executor.submit(() -> {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                int smoothieCount = calculateSmoothiesCount(smoothies);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> resultField.setText(String.valueOf(smoothieCount)));
                Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
}


Demo
Here it is in action. At the bottom, I included a YAML file that can be used as configuration. This makes the application more dynamic. A separate model package makes data more readable and modular.
I also included lombok and SnakeYAML as dependencies:

implementation: 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.3'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.36'

package org.example.smoothies;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.example.smoothies.model.Ingredients;
import org.example.smoothies.model.Smoothie;
import org.example.smoothies.model.SmoothiesWrapper;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor;

public class SmoothieApp {
    private static final String[] INGREDIENTS_LIST = {
            "apple", "butter", "cactus", "egg", "fang", "grapes",
            "guts", "horse", "kelp", "mango", "milk", "nectar",
            "pepper", "potato", "pumpkin", "salt"
    };
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
    private static final int GRID_ROWS = 8;
    private static final int GRID_COLUMNS = 2;
    private static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS = 500;

    private final List<JCheckBox> ingredientCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    private final JTextField resultField = new JTextField("hai :D");
    private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public SmoothieApp(List<Smoothie> smoothies) {
        JFrame frame = initializeUI(smoothies);
        startSmoothieUpdater(smoothies);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JFrame initializeUI(List<Smoothie> smoothies) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Smoothie Maker");
        frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.add(createIngredientPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(resultField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createCalculateButton(smoothies), BorderLayout.EAST);

        resultField.setEditable(false);

        return frame;
    }

    private JPanel createIngredientPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(GRID_ROWS, GRID_COLUMNS));
        for (String ingredient : INGREDIENTS_LIST) {
            JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(ingredient);
            ingredientCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
            panel.add(checkBox);
        }
        return panel;
    }

    private JButton createCalculateButton(List<Smoothie> smoothies) {
        JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(e -> displayPossibleSmoothies(smoothies));
        return calculateButton;
    }

    private void displayPossibleSmoothies(List<Smoothie> smoothies) {
        System.out.println("\n=== SMOOTHIES YOU CAN MAKE ===");
        boolean smoothiesFound = false;

        for (Smoothie smoothie : smoothies) {
            Ingredients ingredients = smoothie.getIngredients();
            if (canMakeSmoothie(ingredients)) {
                smoothiesFound = true;
                System.out.printf("Smoothie: %s%n", smoothie.getName());
                System.out.printf("  - Required: %s%n", String.join(", ", ingredients.getRequired()));
                System.out.printf("  - Optional: %s%n%n", String.join(", ", ingredients.getOptional()));
            }
        }

        if (!smoothiesFound) {
            System.out.println("No smoothies can be made with the selected ingredients.");
        }

        System.out.println("================================");
    }

    private boolean canMakeSmoothie(Ingredients ingredients) {
        return ingredients.getRequired().stream().anyMatch(this::isIngredientSelected) &&
                ingredients.getOptional().stream().anyMatch(this::isIngredientSelected);
    }

    private boolean isIngredientSelected(String ingredient) {
        return ingredientCheckBoxes.stream()
                .anyMatch(box -> box.getText().equals(ingredient) && box.isSelected());
    }

    private void startSmoothieUpdater(List<Smoothie> smoothies) {
        executor.submit(() -> {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    int smoothieCount = calculateSmoothiesCount(smoothies);
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> resultField.setText(String.valueOf(smoothieCount)));
                    Thread.sleep(UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private int calculateSmoothiesCount(List<Smoothie> smoothies) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Smoothie smoothie : smoothies) {
            Ingredients ingredients = smoothie.getIngredients();
            if (canMakeSmoothie(ingredients)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(SmoothiesWrapper.class, new LoaderOptions()));

        try (InputStream inputStream = SmoothieApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("smoothies.yaml")) {
            if (inputStream == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("smoothies.yaml not found");
            }

            SmoothiesWrapper wrapper = yaml.load(inputStream);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SmoothieApp(wrapper.getSmoothies()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load YAML", e);
        }
    }
}

package org.example.smoothies.model;

import java.util.*;
import lombok.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SmoothiesWrapper {
    private List<Smoothie> smoothies;
}

package org.example.smoothies.model;

import lombok.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Smoothie {
    private String name;
    private Ingredients ingredients;
}

package org.example.smoothies.model;

import lombok.*;
import java.util.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Ingredients {
    private List<String> required;
    private List<String> optional;
}

Note: I generated a YAML file (smoothies.yaml) based on all the smoothie possibilities from your original code:
smoothies:
  - name: Nectar Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["nectar"]
      optional: ["nectar"]
  - name: Nectar Milkshake
    ingredients:
      required: ["nectar"]
      optional: ["milk"]
  - name: Grape Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["grapes"]
      optional: ["grapes"]
  - name: Grape Medley
    ingredients:
      required: ["grapes"]
      optional: ["horse", "apple", "cactus", "salt", "butter", "mango"]
  - name: Grape Nectar Blend
    ingredients:
      required: ["grapes"]
      optional: ["nectar"]
  - name: Grape Milkshake
    ingredients:
      required: ["grapes"]
      optional: ["milk"]
  - name: Double Milkshake
    ingredients:
      required: ["milk"]
      optional: ["milk"]
  - name: Milk Cactus Delight
    ingredients:
      required: ["milk"]
      optional: ["apple", "cactus"]
  - name: Milk with a Dash of Salt
    ingredients:
      required: ["milk"]
      optional: ["salt"]
  - name: Mango Puree
    ingredients:
      required: ["mango"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Mango Adventure
    ingredients:
      required: ["mango"]
      optional: ["kelp", "apple", "cactus", "butter"]
  - name: Nectar Mango Fusion
    ingredients:
      required: ["nectar"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Milk Mango Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["milk"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Salted Mango Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["salt"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Cactus Delight
    ingredients:
      required: ["cactus"]
      optional: ["cactus", "horse", "nectar", "pumpkin"]
  - name: Cactus and Salt Combo
    ingredients:
      required: ["cactus"]
      optional: ["salt"]
  - name: Pepper Explosion
    ingredients:
      required: ["pepper"]
      optional: ["pepper"]
  - name: Spicy Cactus Pumpkin Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["pepper"]
      optional: ["cactus", "pumpkin"]
  - name: Pepper Potato Mashup
    ingredients:
      required: ["pepper"]
      optional: ["potato"]
  - name: Pepper Grape Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["pepper"]
      optional: ["grapes", "apple", "milk", "mango"]
  - name: Apple Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["apple"]
      optional: ["apple"]
  - name: Apple Adventure
    ingredients:
      required: ["apple"]
      optional: ["horse", "nectar", "cactus", "potato"]
  - name: Salted Apple Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["apple"]
      optional: ["salt"]
  - name: Kelp Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["kelp"]
      optional: ["kelp"]
  - name: Kelp Fruit Blend
    ingredients:
      required: ["kelp"]
      optional: ["grapes", "apple", "potato"]
  - name: Pumpkin with a Hint of Kelp
    ingredients:
      required: ["kelp"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]
  - name: Kelp Milkshake
    ingredients:
      required: ["kelp"]
      optional: ["milk"]
  - name: Salted Kelp Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["kelp"]
      optional: ["salt"]
  - name: Horsepower Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["horse"]
      optional: ["horse", "kelp", "pepper", "nectar", "potato", "salt", "mango"]
  - name: Horse Milkshake
    ingredients:
      required: ["horse"]
      optional: ["milk"]
  - name: Potato Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["potato"]
      optional: ["potato"]
  - name: Potato Grape Mashup
    ingredients:
      required: ["potato"]
      optional: ["grapes", "cactus", "butter"]
  - name: Potato Nectar Blend
    ingredients:
      required: ["nectar"]
      optional: ["potato"]
  - name: Milk Potato Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["milk"]
      optional: ["potato"]
  - name: Mango Potato Fusion
    ingredients:
      required: ["potato"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Salted Potato
    ingredients:
      required: ["potato"]
      optional: ["salt"]
  - name: Butter Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["butter"]
      optional: ["butter", "kelp"]
  - name: Apple Butter Delight
    ingredients:
      required: ["apple"]
      optional: ["butter"]
  - name: Cactus Butter Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["cactus"]
      optional: ["butter"]
  - name: Butter Nectar Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["nectar"]
      optional: ["butter"]
  - name: Butter Pumpkin Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["butter"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]
  - name: Milk Butter Combo
    ingredients:
      required: ["milk"]
      optional: ["butter"]
  - name: Salted Butter Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["salt"]
      optional: ["butter"]
  - name: Pumpkin Delight
    ingredients:
      required: ["pumpkin"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]
  - name: Pumpkin Harvest
    ingredients:
      required: ["pumpkin"]
      optional: ["horse", "grapes", "apple", "potato"]
  - name: Pumpkin Nectar Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["nectar"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]
  - name: Milk Pumpkin Fusion
    ingredients:
      required: ["milk"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]
  - name: Pumpkin Mango Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["pumpkin"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Salted Pumpkin Blend
    ingredients:
      required: ["salt"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]
  - name: Egg Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["egg", "grapes", "nectar", "milk", "salt"]
  - name: Mango Egg Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Egg and Cactus Combo
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["cactus"]
  - name: Spicy Egg
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["pepper"]
  - name: Apple Egg Delight
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["apple"]
  - name: Egg and Kelp Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["kelp"]
  - name: Horse Egg Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["horse"]
  - name: Potato Egg Combo
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["potato"]
  - name: Buttered Egg Delight
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["butter"]
  - name: Pumpkin Egg Fusion
    ingredients:
      required: ["egg"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]
  - name: Gutsy Mango Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["guts"]
      optional: ["mango"]
  - name: Guts and Cactus Combo
    ingredients:
      required: ["guts"]
      optional: ["cactus"]
  - name: Fang Pepper Mashup
    ingredients:
      required: ["fang"]
      optional: ["pepper"]
  - name: Gutsy Pepper Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["guts"]
      optional: ["pepper"]
  - name: Apple Guts Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["guts"]
      optional: ["apple"]
  - name: Fang Kelp Mix
    ingredients:
      required: ["fang"]
      optional: ["kelp"]
  - name: Horse Fang Smoothie
    ingredients:
      required: ["fang"]
      optional: ["horse"]
  - name: Potato Fang Delight
    ingredients:
      required: ["fang"]
      optional: ["potato"]
  - name: Butter Fang Fusion
    ingredients:
      required: ["fang"]
      optional: ["butter"]
  - name: Pumpkin Fang Combo
    ingredients:
      required: ["fang"]
      optional: ["pumpkin"]

